# A form with labels over the inputs but also label and input inline using Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a form that looks like this:

```
Order    Person      City           Street
1234     Joe         Hull           Coronation


Date         Phone
1/1/2001     051-666-333
```

The default style gives me the label over the input but then it stacks all the inputs one on top of each other.

Is there some way I could achieve the label over the input but also have all the fields follow each other inline?  Please note that I want to try and stick with as much of the twitter framework as possible so I think it's important not to add too much additional markup or divs.

Comment: what does your current markup / css look like - i would guess that the problem will be a CSS one not a framework problem

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this has anything to do with jQuery like @ManseUK said this is probably a css issue. I am not sure if you are surrounding this in a  element or not but you should be able to do this with rows in bootstrap and then float the control groups

http://jsfiddle.net/billpull/uWeW5/

add a class like this to your css or whatever you want to name it depending on any other possible other properties

```
.float-left {
   float: left;
}
```

and change your html code to something like this.

```
         <div class="row">
            <div class="control-group float-left">
                <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group float-left">
                <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group float-left">
                <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="control-group float-left">
                <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group float-left">
                <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

depending on your width restrictions you may want to use bootstrap's grid system rather than floating.